# How Do I Bind An Angular Reactive Control Method to ngModel?

Tags: angular

index.html:

```
<textarea id="w3review" (change)="textRelease()"[{ngModel}]="this.getCaptionDetail.value.caption">{{this.getDetailText.caption}}
```

I am having trouble getting my reactive controls to bind in Angular.

component.ts:

```
....

getDetailText() {
    let index = this.detailIndex
    let detailArray = 
    this.detailsControl.controls[this.selectedHour] as FormArray
    let detailGroup = detailArray.at(index) as FormGroup
    let value = detailGroup.value
    return value
}
....

textRelease() {
    var hour = this.selectedHour.slice(0,4)
    var index = this.detailIndex
    var baseKey = this.parse(index, this.selectedHour.slice(0, 4));
    var theGroup = this.detailsControl.get(this.selectedHour) as FormArray
    var theControl = theGroup.at(this.detailIndex) as FormControl
    let theKey = hour + baseKey
    this.db.putItem(this.data.dataObject['name'], theControl);
}
....
```

I am expecting to be able to get the last entered text from the textarea by getting a reference to the particular control. (which is nested in other abstract controls) Unfortunately the ngModel part: [{ngModel}]="this.getCaptionDetail.caption"> doesn't seem bound correctly.

Comment: maybe because you are using it wrong? it is `[(ngModel)]`, not `[{ngModel}]`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking to bind a formControl (https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#adding-a-basic-form-control), ngModel binds values. You can bind a value to element in the template with ngModel but if you already have a form then you should bind the control with formControl.